# Canvas Clearing After Multiple DrawImage

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to draw a tile-like map to the canvas, although if i try to draw the same sprite twice, it will only render the final call of drawImage. Here is my code if it helps :

```js
window.onload = function(){
 function get(id){
  return document.getElementById(id);
 }

 var canvas = get("canvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 canvas.width = 160;
 canvas.height = 160;

 grass = new Image();
 water = new Image();

 grass.src = "res/Grass.png";
 water.src = "res/Water.png";

 
 path = {
  draw: function(image,X,Y){
   X = (X*32)-32;
   Y = (Y*32)-32;
 
   image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(image,X,Y);
   }  
  },
 }

 path.draw(water,2,2);
 path.draw(grass,1,2);
 path.draw(grass,1,1);
 path.draw(water,2,1);
 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `onload` on the image next time you call it.

Think of it this way:

```js
var image = {
  onload: null
};

// Wait for the image to "load"
// Remember, onload is asynchronous so it won't be called until the rest of
// your code is done and the image is loaded
setTimeout(function() {
  image.onload();
}, 500);

image.onload = function() {
  console.log('I will never be called');
};

image.onload = function() {
  console.log('I overwrite the previous one');
};
```

Instead, you might try waiting for your images to load *then* do the rest of your logic.

```js
var numOfImagesLoading = 0;
var firstImage = new Image();
var secondImage = new Image();

// This is called when an image finishes loading
function onLoad() {
  numOfImagesLoading -= 1;
  if (numOfImagesLoading === 0) {
    doStuff();
  }
}

function doStuff() {
  // This is where you can use your images
  document.body.appendChild(firstImage);
  document.body.appendChild(secondImage);
}

firstImage.src = 'http://placehold.it/100x100';
firstImage.onload = onLoad;
numOfImagesLoading += 1;

secondImage.src = 'http://placehold.it/200x200';
secondImage.onload = onLoad;
numOfImagesLoading += 1;
```